# Reformat an existing data table into single line entries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get all entries from an existing SQL Server table for the same `job_number` field on a single row. For example, I want to take the following table:

```
+--------------+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+
| Company_Code | Job_Number | User_Def_Sequence | Alpha_Field | Date_Field | Amount_Field |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+
| ABC          | 02-0294-00 |            000001 |             | NULL       |     0.000000 |
| ABC          | 02-0294-00 |            000003 |             | NULL       |     0.000000 |
| ABC          | 02-0294-00 |            000006 |             | NULL       |     0.000000 |
| ABC          | 02-0418-00 |            000001 |             | NULL       |     0.000000 |
| ABC          | 02-0418-00 |            000002 |             | NULL       |     0.000000 |
| ABC          | 02-0418-00 |            000003 | 15-02-0065  | NULL       |     0.000000 |
| ABC          | 02-0424-00 |            000003 | 15-02-0095  | NULL       |     0.000000 |
| ABC          | 02-0431-00 |            000003 | 15-02-0095  | NULL       |     0.000000 |
| ABC          | 02-0435-00 |            000003 | 15-02-0102  | NULL       |     0.000000 |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+
```

and convert it into something like this:

```
+--------------+------------+--------+------------+--------+----------+--------+---------+--------+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+
| Company_Code | Job_Number | UDS_1  |  Alpha_1   | Date_1 | Amount_1 | UDS_2  | Alpha_2 | Date_2 | Amount_2 | UDS_3  |  Alpha_3   | Date_3 | Amount_3 |
+--------------+------------+--------+------------+--------+----------+--------+---------+--------+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+
| ABC          | 02-0294-00 | 000001 |            | NULL   | 0.000000 | 000003 |         | NULL   | 0.000000 | 000006 |            | NULL   | 0.000000 |
| ABC          | 02-0418-00 | 000001 |            | NULL   | 0.000000 | 000002 |         | NULL   | 0.000000 | 000003 | 15-02-0065 | NULL   | 0.000000 |
| ABC          | 02-0424-00 | 000003 | 15-02-0065 | NULL   | 0.000000 |        |         |        |          |        |            |        |          |
| ABC          | 02-0431-00 | 000003 | 15-02-0095 | NULL   | 0.000000 |        |         |        |          |        |            |        |          |
| ABC          | 02-0435-00 | 000003 | 15-02-0102 | NULL   | 0.000000 |        |         |        |          |        |            |        |          |
+--------------+------------+--------+------------+--------+----------+--------+---------+--------+----------+--------+------------+--------+----------+
```

Edit: Each job number may have multiple `User_Def_Sequence` variations which need to be appended to the same row along with their value.

What is the best method of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select Company_Code, Job_Number,
       min(User_Def_Sequence),
       min(Alpha_Field),
       min(Alpha_Field),
       min(Amount_Field),
       . . .
from t
group by Company_Code, Job_Number;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this option does not bring in all the variations of the `User_Def_Sequence` field each job number may have up to 8 different `User_Def_Sequence` variations. I need something that will append each variation of the `User_Def_Sequence` field to the same row with it's value.

Comment: @bradsdb . . . Then you would use `string_agg()`, but I don't see any hint of that requirement in the question.

Comment: Apologies, I think my comment may have confused this a bit further. I don't need all 8 variations of `User_Def_Sequence` in a single string, I am just trying to get all variations as different columns. I'm not sure the best way to word that which is why I tried to demonstrate via the sample tables of what the conversion should look like.

Comment: I updated the answer with the code that I used, thanks for your help!